# Como hacer que el for sea SÍCRONO, para que la funcion no se ejecute desordenada

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que encripta y desencripta un texto simple (sin espacio), y al encriptar mi texto segun el abecedario, me retorna la encriptación con caracteres correctos pero desordenados, por ejemplo si encripto "hola" me devuelve "krod" y si desencripto "krod" me devuelve "hloa", no se si me explique bien. ¡Espero me puedan ayudar!

Hello, I am doing a program that encrypts and decrypts simple text (without space), and when I encrypt my text according to the alphabet, it returns me the encryption with correct but messy characters, for example if encrypted "hello" returns "krod" and if decrypted "krod" returns "hloa", I don't know if it explains well to me. I hope you can help me!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        
        var abc=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

        function encri(element){
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                var letra = element.charAt(i);
                var posicion = abc.indexOf(letra);
                if (posicion == 23) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion-23]);
                }
                if (posicion == 24) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion-23]);
                }
                if (posicion == 25) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion-23]);
                }
                else{
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion+3]);
                }
                
            }
            return element;
        };

        function desencri(element){
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                var letra = element.charAt(i);
                var posicion = abc.indexOf(letra);
                if (posicion == 0) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion+23]);
                }
                if (posicion == 1) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion+23]);
                }
                if (posicion == 2) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion+23]);
                }
                else{
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion-3]);
                }
            }

            return element;
        };


        function encriptar(elemento){
            var palabra = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            var palabra_codificada = encri(palabra);
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = palabra_codificada;
        };

        function desencriptar(elemento){
            var palabra = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            var palabra_decodificada = desencri(palabra);
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = palabra_decodificada;
        };
    </script>
    <h1 id="titulo">Bienvenido al Encriptador de letras</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su texto sin espacios..." id="caja"> <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="encriptar()" class="btn-encri">Encriptar</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="desencriptar()" class="btn-desencri">Desencriptar</button>
    <p id="resultado">Aquí aparecera su resultado.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, por favor edita tu pregunta y elimina la parte en inglés, ya que estás en [es.so] y la idea es que todo sea en Castellano. Tu traducción al inglés entonces no es relevante. Espero no lo tomes a mal. Es parte de las reglas del sitio. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido.
Tu problema no tiene que ver con sincronía, sino con el método "replace" del prototype string. Ya que busca el primer caracter que incluya.

Para una solución sencilla, solo necesitas agregar una variable más para que se vaya concatenando el resultado y así no necesitarías reemplazar.

También nota, que quité las condiciones y las uní con &&

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        let abc=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
        let result = ""
        function encri(element){
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                let letra = element.charAt(i);
                let posicion = abc.indexOf(letra);
                if (posicion >= 23 && posicion <=25) {
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion-23]);
                    result = result + abc[posicion-23]  
                }
                else{
                    element = element.replace(letra,abc[posicion+3]);
                    result = result + abc[posicion+3]  
                }

            }
            return element;
        };

         function desencri(element){
           let result = ""
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                let letra = element.charAt(i);
                let posicion = abc.indexOf(letra);
                if (posicion >= 0 && posicion<=2) {
                    element =  element.replace(letra,abc[posicion+23]);
                }
                else{
                    element =  element.replace(letra,abc[posicion-3]);
                    result = result + abc[posicion-3]                          
                }
            }

            return result;
        };


        function  encriptar (elemento){
            let palabra = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            let palabra_codificada = encri(palabra);
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = palabra_codificada;
        };

         function desencriptar(elemento){
            let palabra = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            let palabra_decodificada =  desencri(palabra);
            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = palabra_decodificada;
        };
    </script>
    <h1 id="titulo">Bienvenido al Encriptador de letras</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su texto sin espacios..." id="caja"> <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="encriptar()" class="btn-encri">Encriptar</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="desencriptar()" class="btn-desencri">Desencriptar</button>
    <p id="resultado">Aquí aparecera su resultado.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero te pueda servir

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió mucho, ahí arregle unas cositas como poner el primer let result=""; dentro de la funcion para que el valor vuelva a estar vacío, y también agregar el result += abc[posicion] al desencriptar. Pero todo muy bien muchas gracias!